# Content wrapping for lists using CSS or HTML or JavaScript?

Tags: html, css

I am curious how I would get content to wrap around the elements like at the link below. The flex-wrap feature does get them to wrap around somewhat but it leaves a lot of white space as demonstrated in the second link.

http://saijogeorge.com/website-builders/

[My source code and demo here](http://ittybittyurl.com/Z5e)

Comment: Hi again @Diana. Just checking if my answer successfully answered your question? If so, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This prevents this question from showing up on the 'Unanswered' tab. If not, can you please list any problems you're still facing, so that I can try to help you further. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to possible to solve with just CSS. Saijo George solves the problem by using inline absolute positioning, controlled through JavaScript.

For example, `#bot-builders` has a default inline style of: `position: absolute; top: 130px; left: 400px;`. These variables change whenever the browser is resized.

Adding the above to your example solves the problem, though naturally messes up the display at different widths. You could create a bunch of media queries to change *every single* list's values at *multiple* widths, though that would seem a bit overkill. Ultimately, you may need to contact Saijo George to find out exactly what JavaScript they are using to control the responsiveness.

Hope this helps!